# Why TypeScript path aliases are not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I have a TypeScript project with the following directory structure:

```
|- packages
| |- some-package
| |  |- src
| |     |- index.ts
| |- another-package
|    |- src
|       |- index.ts
|- tsconfig.json
|- package.json
```

The `tsconfig.json` file has the following content:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./packages",
    "paths": {
      "@company/some-package/*": ["some-package/src/*"],
      "@company/another-package/*": ["another-package/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

`some-package/src/index.ts` has the following content:

```js
export type SomeType = {
   prop: string
}
```

`another-package/src/index.ts` has the following content:

```js
import { SomeType } from '@company/some-ackage'
```

I am having the following error on `another-package/src/index.ts` when opening the project in Visual Studio Code:

> Cannot find module '@company/some-package' or its corresponding type declarations.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `@company/some-package/*` matches `@company/some-package`.

---

I think typically you make a package have one export file, and set things up to import that.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./packages",
    "paths": {
      "@company/some-package": ["some-package/src/index.ts"],
      "@company/another-package": ["another-package/src/index.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
// some-package/src/index.ts
import * from './file-a'
import * from './file-b'

// Or just put things directly in here
export type SomeType = {
   prop: string
}
```

Comment: Yes, in a real project  all the `index.ts` files would not declare/use any values/types, it would just act as a barrel. For the sake of making the example less verbose i just made it this way. I don't see how it would interfere on the aliases being correctly resolved; Considering the alias points to a folder (`src`) I was expecting typescript to look for `index.ts`  implicitly.

Comment: In addition, I tried what you suggested but it haven't worked.